# Rendering nodes of a same content type in different templates

Tags: theming

My Client would like to have multiple templates for one content type. How to allow a user in Drupal to select a specific template when creating a node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are looking for [Template Picker](https://www.drupal.org/project/template_picker) module:

> Template picker gives content creators a list of templates to choose from as they create nodes.

[image: Image from official module page]